# FatalThrowableError in MailgunTransport.php line 67: Undefined class constant 'VERSION'

Tags: php, laravel-5, mailgun

I'm getting this error when trying to send email from within my Laravel 5.1 application. This function was working quite well for a very long time, but I stopped using my application for about a year and now when I try to use it I'm getting this error. I don't think I've made any changes to anything related to emails, so I'm not sure what the cause could be.

Here is what my composer.json looks like:

```
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.1",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
        "nesbot/carbon": "1.39.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.0",
        "silber/bouncer": " v1.0.0-rc.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "v2.9",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^4.0.0",
        "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
```

EDIT:

Here is what the MailgunTransport.php file looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Mail\Transport;

use Swift_Mime_Message;
use GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;

class MailgunTransport extends Transport
{
    /**
     * Guzzle client instance.
     *
     * @var \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * The Mailgun API key.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $key;

    /**
     * The Mailgun domain.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $domain;

    /**
     * THe Mailgun API end-point.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * Create a new Mailgun transport instance.
     *
     * @param  \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface  $client
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  string  $domain
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, $key, $domain)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->setDomain($domain);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        $this->beforeSendPerformed($message);

        $options = ['auth' => ['api', $this->key]];

        $to = $this->getTo($message);

        $message->setBcc([]);

        if (version_compare(ClientInterface::VERSION, '6') === 1) {
            $options['multipart'] = [
                ['name' => 'to', 'contents' => $to],
                ['name' => 'message', 'contents' => $message->toString(), 'filename' => 'message.mime'],
            ];
        } else {
            $options['body'] = [
                'to' => $to,
                'message' => new PostFile('message', $message->toString()),
            ];
        }

        return $this->client->post($this->url, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Get the "to" payload field for the API request.
     *
     * @param  \Swift_Mime_Message  $message
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTo(Swift_Mime_Message $message)
    {
        $formatted = [];

        $contacts = array_merge(
            (array) $message->getTo(), (array) $message->getCc(), (array) $message->getBcc()
        );

        foreach ($contacts as $address => $display) {
            $formatted[] = $display ? $display." <$address>" : $address;
        }

        return implode(',', $formatted);
    }

    /**
     * Get the API key being used by the transport.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    /**
     * Set the API key being used by the transport.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return string
     */
    public function setKey($key)
    {
        return $this->key = $key;
    }

    /**
     * Get the domain being used by the transport.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDomain()
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    /**
     * Set the domain being used by the transport.
     *
     * @param  string  $domain
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDomain($domain)
    {
        $this->url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/'.$domain.'/messages.mime';

        return $this->domain = $domain;
    }
}
```

Please note that this file is generated from the Mailgun source code, nothing in that file was created by me.

Line 67 is this one:

`if (version_compare(ClientInterface::VERSION, '6') === 1)`

After running `composer update` as suggested in the replies, I get the following warnings:

```
Package anahkiasen/underscore-php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Package jeremeamia/superclosure is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use opis/closure instead.
Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
Package patchwork/utf8 is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/polyfill-mbstring or symfony/string instead.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
```

I'm wondering if maybe the swiftmailer is causing the issue...I'm not sure how to get it to use symfony mailer as recommended.

Comment: Where does MailgunTransport.php come from? I see nothing in your composer.json related to Mailgun.

Comment: It’s built into the Laravel framework. I only included the composer file to show what versions of PHP and Laravel (etc.) that I’m using.

Comment: We need MailgunTransport.php or at minimum line 65-69 of it along with any definitions of VERSION in that file or others.

Comment: @JamesRisner I’m not sure what you mean

Comment: Your title: FatalThrowableError in MailgunTransport.php line 67: Undefined class constant 'VERSION' --- Indicates an issue on line 67 of MailgunTransport.php. We would need to see at minimum line 67. Preferably most if not all.

Comment: We need more information like what you have already tried and what's in `MailgunTransport.php` file.

Comment: Very sorry for the delay, I've added the `MailgunTransport.php` file contents as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you said it was fine before, seems like you just need to update dependencies to their minor updates.

1. Firstly, backup your `composer.json` file and run `composer update`
   and see it helps.
2. If it doesn't help, you might need to install Guzzle. [According to
   laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#introduction:%7E:text=All%20of%20the%20API%20drivers%20require%20that%20the%20Guzzle%20HTTP%20library%20be%20installed%20for%20your%20application.),

   - you need to add `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"`
     to your `composer.json`
   - delete `composer.lock` file
   - and run `composer install`

With `composer.lock` file presence, `composer install` will only look into that file and install versions defined
in there.

[image]

3. If it still not help, just replace the backed-up `composer.json`
   back and run `composer install` to rollback your dependencies. Then
   show me `MailgunTransport.php` file for further investigation.

Comment: Running composer update did not help, although it did give me some error messages (added to my question) and now I wonder if swiftmailer isn't the issue, it says it's abandoned and to use symfony mailer instead. Also, I think Guzzle is installed with Laravel, because it does exist in the vendor file but it isn't in the composer.json file. Currently it's showing version 7.4.5 installed.

Comment: There you go! The doc suggested version of guzzle is `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"` but you said you have `7.4.5` installed. Downgrade the guzzle by adding `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"` to your `composer.json` and run `composer install` to install the defined version. 

Since the doc mentioned `~`, guzzlehttp version should not be larger than 5.4 or 6.1. Read more about the versions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/2218290

Comment: I did as you suggested but I get the same error. My vendor folder is also showing the same version as before, is there a way to confirm which version is installed?

Comment: Also, do you know how my version would go up to 7.4.5? Since I didn't have it in my composer file previously, I thought it was part of the Laravel package, which I assumed would control which versions of the dependencies would be installed, no?

Comment: You can use `composer show -i | grep guzzlehttp/guzzle` command to see the installed guzzle version.

"which I assumed would control which versions of the dependencies would be installed, no?"
Yes, your app's dependencies can have their own dependencies with their defined `composer.json` files. You can find them in packages' folder.

Comment: @AndrewFox As you can see [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/a52f0440530b54fa079ce76e8c5d196a42cad981/src/ClientInterface.php#L13), `ClientInterface::VERSION` was deprecated in version 6 and removed in 7.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, thank you for taking the time to reply. I'm not sure how I can force the version of Guzzle to be less than 7.4.5. After I added the specific version needed in my composer.json and installed everything, it was still that newer version. I assume that's because something else is controlling which version gets installed.

Comment: I just tried adding the version to my composer.json file again, and then running `composer update`, and it's now working! THANK YOU!!! Bounty coming your way tomorrow 

Comment: Glad to hear! I realized what happened. `composer.lock` file must be deleted before running `composer install`. I will add it in the answer.